# two Popen processes are colliding (in python 3.6.8)

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, subprocess, python-3.6

I'm using python 3.6.8 and I have a situation when one process cannot continue until other one is finished.

- p1 is in the main thread and must stay opened for a long time doing things.
- p2 must run in separate thread (daemon=True), read stdout/err using communicate() and finish.

(all pipes are needed, must not disable them)

As you will see below, when run code by python 3.10.4 I have output "thread.popen/communicate", but python 3.6.8 will not print this line.
it will stuck inside communicate() i think.

What I ask for is I need a **workaround** for 3.6.8 and optionally explanation what is going on with Python 3.6.8? a bug with Locks or maybe Pipes?
Thank you!

```py
import threading
from time import sleep
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def run():
    print('thread')
    p2 = Popen('git', stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
    o,e = p2.communicate()
    print('thread.popen/communicate')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=run, daemon=True).start()

    p1 = Popen('cmd', stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
    print('main.popen')
#    p1.wait()
    sleep(2)
```

```py
F:\MySSDPrograms\cudatext\py\cuda_lsp>python.exe new.py
thread
main.popen
thread.popen/communicate

F:\MySSDPrograms\cudatext\py\cuda_lsp>f:\Python36\python.exe new.py
thread
main.popen
```

Comment: `communicate()` is synchronous, it will block until the process exits. Most likely you need to use `Popen` + a suitable number of threads for pumping the I/O streams.

Comment: thanks for answer. AFAIK, communicate() has threads that pump I/O streams. And it should not block when you are only reading Output. Python 3.10 works. I just want to know if there is a workaround for 3.6.

Comment: Just `git` simply prints an error message and exits. Presumably your `p2` wants to do something useful with its output ...? `communicate()` definitely does not have threads, and it definitely blocks in both 3.6 and 3.10 but it's not hard to find questions about how to read without blocking; the [Stack Overflow `subprocess` tag info page](/tags/subprocess/info) has links to a couple of canonicals around this topic.

Comment: @tripleee Yes. you are right. `git` simply prints something and exists. and `communicate()` will not wait longer then that. it will unblock immediatley after reading `stdout` of `git`. that is what I mean by that it should not block. (sorry for confusion.) yes, it reads without threads, and it unblocks immediately after reading output of `git` command.  
The problem is that `p2.communicate()` blocks until `p1` is closed. They are separate processes, they should not "collide" like this. but it happens on python 3.6.

Comment: @tripleee. It turns out that it is a bug of Python 3.6. https://bugs.python.org/issue19764  
"subprocess.Popen has a race condition on Windows with file descriptors: if two threads spawn subprocesses at the same time, unwanted file descriptors may be inherited ..."  
This bug (was fixed in 3.7.0 alpha 4)